# Scrapy request not getting an actual response

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I am having some issues with my scrapy spider.  Most of the time, when I send a request, a response is sent back and data can be scraped just fine.

The problem is that, sometimes, no response comes at all. It seemed weird, so I checked the scrapy shell followed by the URL that got no response, then viewed the response and it actually existed. So some responses are not being scraped and I have no idea why, mainly because sometimes the problem occurs but most of the time it does not.

In regards of my spider settings, Im running as a mozilla user with Robots.txt not obeyed.

Any idea on what could be going on?

Comment: Most likely you are being detected as a bot.

Comment: Any idea on how to avoid detection? I have had similar issues before but setting an user agent fixed it back then.

Comment: How about respecting other people’s decision to exclude bots from requesting their sites?